# CloudFront authentication for static page

Tags: java, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I have a simple Tomcat-based Java webapp serving the static files using the standard servlet. I would like to use CloudFront to reduce the load of the webapp and improve the speed of the static files delivery. I need my static files to be served only to those requests with a valid authentication cookie. Checking the validity of the cookie must be done in the code. I have not much experience with CloudFront but I imagine it is something like a server-side cache. Now how can I let this cache only work for authenticated requests?
I know that one option would be doing the authentication in my webapp and then redirecting to some temporary URL into CF. But I am afraid it could be slow. May be there is some better solution out there?

One of the reasons behind the authentication requirement is that you pay for the amount of delivered data through CF. If someone was able to get data from my CF without control I could end up paying a lot of money.

Thanks for any hints, I am rather a newbie on SO as well as AWS. I tried to google out the answer quite some time and also searched here in SO but found nothing.

Comment: did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide a signed URL to your users. Check it out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

> When you create signed URLs or signed cookies to control access to
>   your objects, you can specify the following restrictions:
>
> - An ending date and time, after which the URL is no longer valid.
> - (Optional) The date and time that the URL becomes valid.
> - (Optional) The IP address or range of addresses of the computers that can be used to access your content.
>
> One part of a signed URL or a signed cookie is hashed and signed using
>   the private key from a public/private key pair. When someone uses a
>   signed URL or signed cookie to access an object, CloudFront compares
>   the signed and unsigned portions of the URL or cookie. If they don't
>   match, CloudFront doesn't serve the object.

Comment: Yes, it is probably the correct answer for my question, although in real life I will need to resort to the redirect because I want the authentication to have rather a short validity and should not break client caching too. So I will probably use redirect and signed cookies. But given how my question was formulated your answer is probably correct. Thanks.